# Getting no of Orders Within a Specified Date

Tags: magento-1.7, orders

I am trying to a get a list of orders for a particular date.That date is -5 days from today's date.This will check for everday.

```
$_lastWeek = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d") - 5, date("Y")));
$_startOfDay = Mage::app()->getLocale()
    ->date(Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp($_lastWeek))
    ->setTime('00:00:00')
    ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
$_endOfDay = Mage::app()->getLocale()
    ->date(Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp($_lastWeek))
    ->setTime('23:59:59')
    ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
        'from' => $_startOfDay,
        'to'   => $_endOfDay,
        'date' => true
    ))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
```

Even though there are couple of orders on that date, its not returning. If I mention:

```
$date = strtotime('6-7-2013 -5 days');
$_lastWeek = date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

Its returning the number of orders. How do I find number of orders for a date that is -5 days from each day?

Answer (score 2):

I'm on my phone but usually this is due to timezone offset. Daylight Savings and the difference between your locale timezone to UTC are usually to blame.

Orders missing from reports due to time zone are typically towards the beginning or very end of the day so as to fall off the report.

Comment: What do you think is the right way to retrieve orders within a date?

Comment: @philwinkle do we need to specify timezone in the query? I am into same issue where my query gets different no or rows from db and when I filter by date in admin grid it fetches different no of orders.